# Python - Insert parameter with a if condition

Tags: python

Basically, the objetive is to insert a new parameter in a class call with a if condition. I'll comment the structure bellow

```
self.firewalls.append(gcp.compute.Firewall(firewall["name"],
            network=firewall["network"],
            target_tags=["web"],
            source_ranges=firewall["source_ranges"] if firewall["source_ranges"] is not None else None,
            denies=[
                gcp.compute.FirewallDenyArgs(
                    protocol=firewallDeny["protocol"],
                    ports=firewallDeny["ports"] if "ports" in firewall.keys() is not None else None 
                )for firewallDeny in firewall.get("firewall_deny") if firewall.get("firewall_deny") is not None
            ],
            allows=[
                gcp.compute.FirewallAllowArgs(
                    protocol=firewallAllow["protocol"],
                    ports=firewallAllow["ports"] if "ports" in firewall.keys() is not None else None 
                )for firewallAllow in firewall.get("firewall_allow")],
            ))
```

On this Firewall class, only allows **OR** denies fields are allowed, said so, it will must check for if one of these objects is *None* or not

So basically, what is needed in a pseudo-code:

```
if firewall.get("firewall_deny") is None:
    do nothing and dont insert the attribute
else:
    iterate over firewall.get("firewall_deny") and instantiate multiple FirewallDenyArgs
```

The same applies to firewall.get("firewall_apply")

The problem is to do this if-check with a for after verifying if the object is not None.

Comment: Is there  a default value for `denies` parameter? Can't you simply pass `None`?

Comment: @Asocia there is not, unfortunately. If the firewall_deny is None, I cannot considerate adding the denies property :(

Comment: @Asocia I've tried it, and even if it is none, the denies field still exists and it throws a error because the allows field it is there too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can figure all of this out ahead of time in a map.  You would build up your map to have either an `allows` key or a `denies` key, but not both.  Your logic could do whatever it had to do to get the contents of this map right, independent of calling `gcp.compute.Firewall`.

So say you ended up with a map like this:

```
params = {
    'allows':[<FirewallAllowArgs objects>]
}
```

You would then call `gcp.compute.Firewall` like this:

```
self.firewalls.append(gcp.compute.Firewall(firewall["name"],
        network=firewall["network"],
        target_tags=["web"],
        source_ranges=firewall["source_ranges"] if firewall["source_ranges"] is not None else None,
        **params
        ))
```

This will cause the precomputed `denies` or `allows` named parameter to be inserted into the call.